# Ajax PHP contact form not working, Unable to post values

Tags: php, ajax, forms, contacts

I am trying to build a form for my website but It's not working. I have done all the debug but am unable to identify the issue as everything looks fine. Please find the code below:

JS Code:

```
// 13. contact form

if ($("#contactForm").length) {
  setCsrf();
  $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function(event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      // handle the invalid form...
      submitMSG(false);
    } else {
      // everything looks good!
      event.preventDefault();
      submitForm();
    }
  });
}

function submitForm() {
  // Initiate Variables With Form Content
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var comments = $("#comments").val();
  var csrfToken = $("#csrfToken").val();

  if (csrfToken) {
    if (name && email && company && website && description && comments) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/libs/contact-form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&comments=" + comments + "&csrfToken=" + csrfToken,
        success: function success(text) {
          if (text == "success") {
            formSuccess();
          } else {
            submitMSG(false, text);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      submitMSG(false, "Please enter the right information.");
    }
  } else {
    submitMSG(false, "Invalid Token");
  }
}

function formSuccess() {
  $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
  submitMSG(true);
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg) {
  if (valid) {
    $(".message-box").removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block ');
    $(".message-box div").removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').text('Form submitted successfully');
  } else {
    $(".message-box").removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block ');
    $(".message-box div").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger').text('Found error in the form. Please check again.');
  }
}

function setCsrf() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'libs/csrf.php',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function success(data) {
      if (data) {
        document.getElementById("csrfToken").value = data.csrfToken;
      }
    },
    error: function error(_error) {
      console.log("Error " + _error);
    }
  });
```

PHP Code (contact-form-process.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $errorMSG = "";
    
    $name    = $_POST["name"];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];

    $comments = $_POST["comments"];
    
    // CSRF token check
    if(empty($_SESSION["csrfToken"]) || ($_SESSION["csrfToken"] !== $_POST["csrfToken"])) {
        $errorMSG .= "Invalid Token ";
    }
    
    // NAME
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errorMSG .= "Name is required ";
    }
    
    // EMAIL
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
    }
    
    
    
    // MESSAGE
    if (empty($comments)) {
        $errorMSG .= "Comments is required ";
    }
    
    // change email with your email
    $emailTo = "info@****.com";
    $subject = "*** Request";
    
    
    
    
    // prepare email body text
    
    $emailBody = " \n Name: ";
    $emailBody .= $name;
    $emailBody .= "\n";
    
    $emailBody .= "Email: ";
    $emailBody .= $email;
    $emailBody .= "\n";
    
    
    $emailBody .= "Additional Comments: ";
    $emailBody .= $comments;
    $emailBody .= "\n";
    
    // send email
    if(empty($errorMSG)) {
        if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $emailBody, "From:".$email)){
            echo "success";
        }
    } 
    else{
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
 <form action="" method="POST" id="contactForm" class="contact-us-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" id="csrfToken" value="" />
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
            <h2>Become our Partner</h2>
            <p>Fill out the application below and our team will contact you in 24 hours.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="25" placeholder="Add some comments *"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-brand-01" id="btnContactUs"> 
                Apply Now
            </button> 
            
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I keep getting the error "Found error in the form. Please check again."

Please help.

Comment: Please add a line `alert(msg);` before the line `$(".message-box div").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger').text('Found error in the form. Please check again.');` and let us know what message you see.

Comment: @KenLee Here is the response - https://pastebin.com/jCseFsnr

Comment: Shouldn't `data` in your Ajax call be an object, like `{ name: "John", location: "Boston" }` instead of a concatenated string? [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Based on tutorial https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-bootstrap-contact-form-using-php-and-ajax--cms-23068

Comment: Please add `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` at the top of your HTML and retry (let us know the result please)

Comment: Add error_log(print_r($_POST,true)) at the top of your php file and see whats printed in your error log.